# PHP If statement not working as I thought it should

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up some error checking on a form, I have the following so far:

```
 if (empty($fname)) {
        $error = true;
        $error_fname = "Please fill in your first name";
    }else if (empty($lname)) {
        $error = true;
        $error_lname = "Please fill in your first name";
     }
```

And although in the first if statement assigns the string to the variable $error_fname is, the second else if statement does nothing, it doesn't assign the error to the variable.

Any help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meet your first condtion you will never get throw the second, don't use if else but two if and also put your error in an array otherwise you might overwrite it if both condition are met

```
$error_lname = array();
if (empty($fname)) {
    $error = true;
    $error_lname[] = "Please fill in your first name";
}
if (empty($lname)) {
    $error = true;
    $error_lname[] = "Please fill in your last name";
 }
```

If you need two separate errors you might use different variables

```
if (empty($fname)) {
    $error = true;
    $error_fname = "Please fill in your first name";
}
if (empty($lname)) {
    $error = true;
    $error_lname = "Please fill in your last name";
 }
```

Comment: why $error_fname and  $error_lname[] both as array?

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to do an array, but I need individual errors for each field and it seems difficult to pick and choose which error to display depending on which field wasn't filled out correctly.

Comment: @Fabio Yeah that's what I figured. I read Murach's PHP and MySQL book and it's very misleading on this topic. Thank you for clarifying it.

Comment: I'm glad I helped you out!

Answer (score 1):

because when its go for first name do not going for lastname so one time you get one condition true.. look @ firstname is empty the error firsname is true then it does not go for second if .. here is the sample code you just need to give condition separately ..

```
if (empty($fname)) {
    $error = true;
    $error_fname = "Please fill in your first name";
}
 if (empty($lname)) {
    $error = true;
    $error_lname = "Please fill in your Last name";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$error=false;
if (empty($fname)) {
        $error = true;
        $errors []= "Please fill in your first name";
    }

 if (empty($lname)) {
        $error = true;
        $errors[] = "Please fill in your last name";
     }


if($error)
  print_r($errors);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed if you remove the "else":

```
if (empty($fname)) {
        $error = true;
        $error_fname = "Please fill in your first name";
}
if (empty($lname)) {
        $error = true;
        $error_lname = "Please fill in your last name";
}
```

Comment: Fix `$error_lname = "Please fill in your first name";`

Comment: @admdrew, I didn't see that. It was on the OP. I was not paying attention to the error msgs.

Comment: Yeah, definitely. I noticed other answers had fixed it, just wanted to remind you!